# Failing to edit a module imported dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, module

While running python 3.6.3 I am trying to edit a dictionary initialized in a module. Reducing complexity, I have the module Foo.py

```
d_1 = {}
def edit(a,b):
    global d_1
    d_1[a] = b

def remove():
    global d_1
    d_1 = {}
```

And Main.py

```
from Foo import d_1, edit, remove
import Foo

remove()
edit("Test", 1)

print(d_1)
```

Running Main.py prints `{}`, but if I commont out the `remove()`, it printst `{"Test":1}`. In both cases, printing `Foo.d_1` prints `{"Test":1}`.

Why is it different, and is there a way to make `edit` work while before hand calling `remove`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is you are creating a new `dict` in `remove`.
If you use `id` function to check `d_1` id. You will see the difference.

It's better to use `d_1.clear()` instead of `d_1 = {}`.

The reason why `Foo.d_1` is correct is `remove` fn "removed" another `dict` object.
(They are operating different `dict` object.)

Comment: Okay, using ```d_1.clear()``` fixed the issue, but I don't understand why a new object is created. If it was a variable, I can imagine it working that way. But python stores lists and dicts as refrences, right? So why is in this case a new object created?

Comment: When creating new `dict`, `d_1` points to a new object instead of old one. You can use `id` function to check which object it pointed.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to create a class to encapsulate all your methods.

**foo.py**

```
class Dictionnary:
    def __init__(self):
        self.d_1 = {}
        
    def edit(self, a, b):
        self.d_1[a] = b
    
    def remove(self):
        self.d_1 = {}
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.d_1.__str__()
```

**main.py**

```
from foo import Dictionnary

d = Dictionnary()

print("Initialization", d)
d.remove()
print("After remove", d)
d.edit("hello", 1)
print("Edited one time", d)
d.edit("world", ":)")
print("Edited 2 times", d)
d.remove()
print("Removed", d)
```

**Output:**

```
Initialization {}
After remove {}
Edited one time {'hello': 1}
Edited 2 times {'hello': 1, 'world': ':)'}
Removed {}
```

You could also use a static class, so you won't have to initialize it and store the object somewhere.